# UIColor alpha values

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, skscene

I am trying to create the background color of my scene with the following rgb value : (59, 89, 152) but whatever alpha value I add, I never get the desired color. Instead i get back the shades of white and gray. It has become so annoying. I don't know what is wrong. the original color is supposed to be blue like that of facebook.

```
    scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 59, green: 89, blue: 152, alpha: 0.3)
```

I tried all possible ten values from 0.0 to 1.0 in alpha parameter.

Comment: @hamish thank yo! it is duplicate. I apologize and solved the problem :)